# Display JSON array elements as one line in U-SQL

Tags: arrays, json, u-sql

How do I display each JSON array element as a comma separated element in one line, rather than one element per line, in U-SQL?

For example, the JSON file is:

```
{
    "A": {
        "A1": "1",
        "A2": 0
    },
    "B": {
        "B1": "1",
        "B2": 0
    },
   "C": {
        "C1": [
              {
                  "D1": "1"
              },
              {
                  "D2": "2"
              },
              {
                  "D3": "3"
              },
              {
                  "D4": "4"
              },
              {
                  "D5": "5"
              },
              {
                  "D6": "6"
              },
              {
                  "D7": "7"
              }
        ]
    }
```

}

The code to process this fragment for the array C1 is as follows:

```
@sql = SELECT 
       Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(C)["C1"] AS C1_array

       FROM @json;

 OUTPUT @sql TO "test.txt" USING Outputters.Csv(quoting: false);

 @sql2 = SELECT    
         Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(C1_array) AS C1
FROM @sql
     CROSS APPLY
     EXPLODE (Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(C1_array).Values) AS D(C1);


@result =
       SELECT C1["D1"]AS D1,
       C1["D2"] AS D2,
       C1["D3"]AS D3,
       C1["D4"]AS D4,
       C1["D5"]AS D5,
       C1["D6"]AS D6,
       C1["D7"]AS D7,

FROM @sql2;


OUTPUT @result TO "output.txt" USING Outputters.Text();
```

The result that all the array elements print out as one per line, ie, all the D1 through D7 elements are on separate lines.  I want the D1 through D7 elements to be part of the same line, as it is part of the JSON object.

That is:

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

The important part is that the `C1` array contains one item per `D`i. So if you treat it as an item per row, you will get separate rows. In this case you want one row for all of `C1`.

The following does this in two ways: One time you know what the Ds are and one time if you do not know and still want them in one row (now all in one cell).

```
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY JSONBlog.[Newtonsoft.Json];
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY JSONBlog.[Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats]; 

// Get one row per C and get the C1 array as column
@d = EXTRACT C1 string FROM "/Temp/ABCD.txt" USING new Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonExtractor("C");

// Keep one row per C and get all the items from within the C1 array
@d =
    SELECT Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(C1, "[*].*") AS DMap
    FROM @d;

// Get individual items
@d1 = 
    SELECT 
        DMap["[0].D1"] AS D1,
        DMap["[1].D2"] AS D2,
        DMap["[2].D3"] AS D3,
        DMap["[3].D4"] AS D4,
        DMap["[4].D5"] AS D5,
        DMap["[5].D6"] AS D6,
        DMap["[6].D7"] AS D7
    FROM @d;

// Keep it generic and get all item in a single column
@d2 = 
    SELECT String.Join("\t", DMap.Values) AS Ds
    FROM @d;

OUTPUT @d1
TO "/Temp/D-Out1.tsv"
USING Outputters.Tsv();

OUTPUT @d2
TO "/Temp/D-Out2.tsv"
USING Outputters.Tsv(quoting:false);
```

As you can see, the `JsonTuple` function can take a JSONPath expression and then it uses all found paths in the resulting map as keys.